# Need to filter based on a condition in map function

Tags: angular, observable

I am populating highchart in my angular 4 application by passing chartseries. I need to filter the chartseries based on a condition. I am not sure how to add a filter based on a condition in map function. The results object ultimately will contain chartseries object which in turn contains data object. The data object has a element name that equals Commercial option. I think the filter that I have written itself isnt correct as i cant see it filtering.

The structure of this.results object while debugging

[image]

The filter that I want to use is

```
.filter(x=> x.chartSeries.data.find(x=> x.name === "Commercial Option"));
```

and the condition would be based on

```
 if(!this.CommercialPremium)
```

How do I used this condition and filter in my map function in code shared below section TS Code

The second option that i thought of is creating a property

```
get getChartSeries() : Array<NpvAnalysisResult> {
    if(!this.CommercialPremium) {
    return  this.results.filter(x=> x.chartSeries.data.find(x=> x.name == 'Commercial Option'));    
    }
  }
```

Html code

```
<div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
    <div *ngFor="let result of results;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">
        <app-box-plot-chart [series]="result.chartSeries" [moduleName]="moduleName">
        </app-box-plot-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS code

```
processResults() {
    if (!this._npvResults) {
      return;
    }
    this.results = this._npvResults.map((result: NpvAnalysis) => {
        return createNpvAnalysisResult(result);
    })

  }
```

Complete Component code

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NpvAnalysis, NpvAnalysisResult, createNpvAnalysisResult } from '../../../../shared/models/results';
import { ReactiveComponent } from '@wtw/toolkit/src/utils/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-net-present-value-analysis',
  templateUrl: './net-present-value-analysis.component.html',
})
export class NetPresentValueAnalysisComponent extends ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  isExpanded = false;
  showTable = true;
  showProjection = false;
  public selectedAnalysis: NpvAnalysis = null;
  public results: Array<NpvAnalysisResult> = [];
  private chartSeries1 : Array<NpvAnalysisResult> = [];
  public moduleName: string = '';
  @Input() CommercialPremium : boolean;

  @Input() set npvResults(value: Array<NpvAnalysis>) {
    this._npvResults = value;
    this.processResults();
  }

  private _npvResults: Array<NpvAnalysis> = [];

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moduleName = 'npv';
  }

  processResults() {
    if (!this._npvResults) {
      return;
    }
    this.results = this._npvResults.map((result: NpvAnalysis) => {
        return createNpvAnalysisResult(result);
    })

  }

  //.filter(x=> x.chartSeries.data.find(x=> x.name === "Commercial Option"));

  get getChartSeries() : Array<NpvAnalysisResult> {
    if(!this.CommercialPremium) {
    return  this.results.filter(x=> x.chartSeries.data.find(x=> x.name == 'Commercial Option'));    
    }
  } 

  showProjectionClick(i) {
    const results = this._npvResults[i];
    if (results) {
      this.selectedAnalysis = results;
      this.showProjection = true;
    }
  }

  hideProjection() {
    this.selectedAnalysis = null;
    this.showProjection = false;
  }
}
```

Complete html code

```
<div class="card">
    <!-- Net Present Value Analysis -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="nva_heading">
        <a [ngClass]="{'collapsed': !isExpanded}" data-toggle="collapse" href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded"
            role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded" aria-controls="nva">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <span style="margin-left: -15px" class="col-sm-2" tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.TITLE.TOOLTIP'|translate}}">
                        {{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.TITLE.LABEL'|translate}}
                </span>
            </h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="{'show': isExpanded}" id="nva" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nva_heading" data-parent="#nva"
        [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded">
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul *ngIf="!showProjection" class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" [ngClass]="!showTable ? '' : 'active' " class="nav-link " id="table-tab" data-toggle="pill"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="table" (click)="showTable = !showTable" aria-selected="true">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.TABLE'|translate}}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" [ngClass]="showTable ? '' : 'active'  " class="nav-link" id="chart-tab" data-toggle="pill"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="chart" (click)="showTable = !showTable" aria-selected="false">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.CHART'|translate}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div *ngIf="!showProjection" class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <!-- nva table -->
                <div *ngIf="showTable" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="base-strategy-table--nva" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab">
                    <div class="tb-container">

                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results; let i = index;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 view-projection-link">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="showProjectionClick(i)">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.VIEW_PROJECTION'|translate}}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">
                                <h6>{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.CAPTIVE_OPTION'|translate}}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.PREMIUM_PAID'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal|number:'.0-0' }} </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.TAX_DEDUCTION'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.captiveInsTaxDeductionTotal|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.LOAN_TO_PARENT'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{result?.captiveInsLoanToParentTotal|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.CAPITAL_CONTRIBUTION'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.captiveInsCapitalContributionTotal|number:'.0-0'}} </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.DIVIDENT_DISTRIBUTION'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{result?.captiveDividentDistributionTotal|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.TERMINAL_VALUE'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.captiveInsTerminalValueTotal|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 net-cost">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.CAPTIVE_NET_COST'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 net-cost"> {{result?.captiveNetCost|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Commercial Option-->
                        <div *ngIf=CommercialPremium>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">
                                <h6>{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.COMMERCIAL_OPTION'|translate}}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.PREMIUM_PAID'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.commInsPremiumPaidTotal|number:'.0-0'}} </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.TAX_DEDUCTION'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.commInsTaxDeductionTotal|number:'.0-0'}} </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 net-cost">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.COMMERCIAL_NET_COST'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 net-cost">{{result?.commNetCost|number:'.0-0'}} </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Self Insurance Option-->
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">
                                <h6>{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.SELF_INSURANCE_OPTION'|translate}}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.DISCOUNTED_LOSSES_PAID'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{result?.selfInsDiscountedLossesPaidTotal|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.DISCOUNTED_TAX_DEDUCTION'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{result?.selfInsDiscountedTaxDeductionTotal|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row ">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 net-cost">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.SELF_INSURANCE_NET_COST'|translate}}</div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 net-cost">{{result?.selfNetCost|number:'.0-0'}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- nva table -->
                <!-- nva Chart -->
                <div *ngIf="!showTable" class="tab-pane base-strategy-chart fade show active" id="base-strategy-chart--nva" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="chart-tab">
                    <div class="tb-container">
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results; let i = index;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6 view-projection-link">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="showProjectionClick(i)">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.VIEW_PROJECTION'|translate}}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"></div>
                            <div *ngFor="let result of results;" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">
                                <app-box-plot-chart [series]="result.chartSeries" [moduleName]="moduleName">
                                </app-box-plot-chart>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Legend-->
                    <div class="col-12 legend">
                        <div>
                            <span class="captive"></span><span>{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.CAPTIVE_OPTION'|translate}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf=CommercialPremium>
                            <span class="commercial"></span><span>{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.COMMERCIAL_OPTION'|translate}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="self-insurance"></span><span>{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.SELF_INSURANCE_OPTION'|translate}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Legend End-->

                </div>


                <!-- nva Chart End -->
            </div>

            <app-net-present-value-analysis-projection [results]="selectedAnalysis" [CommercialPremium]="commercialPremium" [show]="showProjection" (hideProjection)="hideProjection()"></app-net-present-value-analysis-projection>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Card + Net Present Value Analysis End-->
```

NpvAnalysisResult

```
export interface NpvAnalysisResult extends NpvAnalysis {
    captiveNetCost: number;
    commNetCost: number;
    selfNetCost: number;
    captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal: number;
    captiveInsTaxDeductionTotal: number;
    captiveInsLoanToParentTotal: number;
    captiveInsCapitalContributionTotal: number;
    captiveDividentDistributionTotal: number;
    captiveInsTerminalValueTotal: number;
    commInsPremiumPaidTotal: number;
    commInsTaxDeductionTotal: number;
    selfInsDiscountedLossesPaidTotal: number;
    selfInsDiscountedTaxDeductionTotal: number;
    boxplotChartSeries: any[];
}
```

NpvResults

```
NpvAnalysis extends NpvResults

export interface NpvAnalysis extends NpvResults {
    strategyName: string;
}
```

export interface NpvResults  {

```
    commInsYear: number[];
    commInsPremiumPaid: number[];
    commInsTaxDeduction: number[];
    commInsDiscountedTaxDeduction: number[];
    commInsDiscountedLossesPaid: number[];
    commInsGraphData: number[];
    selfInsYear: number[];
    selfInsDiscountedLossesPaid: number[];
    selfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction: number[];
    selfInsGraphData: number[];
    captiveInsYear: number[];
    captiveInsPremiumPaid: number[];
    captiveInsTaxDeduction: number[];
    captiveInsLoanToParent: number[];
    captiveInsCapitalContribution: number[];
    captiveDividentDistribution: number[];
    captiveInsTerminalValue: number[];
    captiveInsGraphData: number[];
    chartSeries: SeriesGeneric<BoxPlotSeriesData>;
}
```

BoxPlotSeriesData interface

```
export interface BoxPlotSeriesData  {

    low: number;
    q1: number;
    median: number;
    q3: number;
    high: number;
    color: string;
    name: string;
}

class SeriesGeneric<T> { 

    public data: T[];
}
```

Comment: Can you share full code of your case? Its super hard to guess whats happening here

Comment: Aded complete html and component code on request

Comment: What i notice is the filter isnt removing that element. Something wrong with the filter

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you. I tried it and it's working.

```
//here iam declared sample variable
public Results: any;

constructor() {
 //here iam assigning sample data related to you.
    this.Results = {
      chartSeries: {
        data: [
          {
            color: "#123",
            high: 12312,
            low: 12211,
            median: 11,
            name: "Captive Options",
            q1: 12121,
            q2: 1123213
          },
          {
            color: "#123",
            high: 12312,
            low: 12211,
            median: 11,
            name: "Commercial Option",
            q1: 12121,
            q2: 1123213
          },
          {
            color: "#123",
            high: 12312,
            low: 12211,
            median: 111,
            name: "Commercial Option",
            q1: 12121,
            q2: 1123213
          },
        ]
      }
    }

    console.log("Results", this.Results);
    let finalData: any[] = [];

    //here iam comparing name field as commercial option.

    finalData= this.Results.chartSeries.data.filter(o => o.name.toLowerCase() == "commercial option");

    console.log("Final Data", FinalData);

  }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Note:
I am using sample data. Replace with your actual data.

Comment: Here in my code i am not able to do this.results.chartSeries in my code as i get the error property chartSeries does not exist on type NpvAnalysisResult[]

Comment: show your Response full and what about NpvAnalysisResult[]?.